# single letter smb mountpoint on catalina

Tags: terminal, finder, smb

MacOS Catalina (I know I'm not up-to-the-minute, but it's also a mid-2014 MBP) seems to have changed how it handles SMB mounts of single letter shares in the terminal.  For example, this is fine (output of `mount`):

`//user@server/recover on /Volumes/recover (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by localuser)`

These, however, are not:

`//user@server/G on /Volumes/server (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by localuser)`

`//user@server/H on /Volumes/server-1 (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by localuser)`

Prior to Catalina, these were available as /Volumes/G and /Volumes/H, and they still show up as G and H in Finder.  Does anyone know what's going on and how to revert to the old behavior?

Comment: In **macOS Catalina** I can confirm the behavior. In testing, using a two character name works as normal. Sorry I have no information on why the exhibited behavior is occurring with a single character name or how to fix it.